# mysql retrieving unique id from table with division

Tags: mysql

In a table like this

```
ID | Category | Value
1    Device     Computer
1    Location   1st Floor
2    Device     Phone
2    Type       Voip
2    Location   1st Floor
3    Device     Computer
3    Location   2nd Floor
```

How do I get the ID of the where device='computer' and location='1st Floor'? The query is created programmatically and there might be many of these criteria that specifies a single ID in a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Distinct a.id 
from myTable a inner join myTable b
 on a.Id = b.Id
Where a.value = 'Computer' And b.value = '1st Floor' and a.Category = 'Device' and b.Category = 'Location'
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f1d9/4)

Comment: If there is a third criteria set, would it require another join and so on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the join query like this for your problem.

```
select a.ID from MYTABLE a, MYTABLE b where a.ID=b.ID and a.Category='Device'
and a.VALUE='Computer' and b.Category='Location' and b.VALUE='1st Floor';
```

If there is may catogories like this then you must split the table like below.

**TABLES :**

```
Category with columns (CATOGORY_ID, CATOGORY)
Value with columns (VALUE_ID, VALUE)
MYTABLE with columns (ID, CATOGORY_ID, VALUE_ID)
```

then you should use join query.

Comment: If there is a third criteria set, would it require another join and so on?

Comment: With your current schema you need joins for every creteria.